# How can I optimise this pandas workflow?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, optimization, apply, bioinformatics

This logic will be applied to BIG data, I really need to optimise for speed and minimise RAM usage as much as possible and I have taken it about as far as my skills go.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['chr1',33329,17,'''33)'6'4?1&AB=?+..''','''X%&=E&!%,0("&"Y&!'''],
                    ['chr1',33330,15,'''6+'/7=1@><C1*'*''','''X%=E!%,("&"Y&&!'''],
                    ['chr1',33331,13,'''2*3A@/9@CC3--''','''X%E!%,("&"Y&!'''],
                    ['chr1',33332,16,'''4**(,:3)+7-@<(0-''','''X%&E&!%,0("&"Y&!'''],
                    ['chr1',33333,14,'''66(/C=*42A:.&*''','''X%=&!%0("&"&&!''']],
                 columns = ['chrom','pos','depth','phred','map'])

df['phred2'] = df.phred.apply(lambda x: sum(map(lambda x: x-33, map(ord, x))))
df['phred2'] = df.phred2/df.phred.str.len()
df.drop(columns=['phred'], inplace=True)
df['map2'] = df.map.apply(lambda x: sum(map(ord, x)))
df['map2'] = df.map2/df.map.str.len()
df.drop(columns=['map'], inplace=True)

df

chrom   pos depth   phred2  map2
0   chr1    33329   17  18.000000   47.000000
1   chr1    33330   15  18.533333   47.533333
2   chr1    33331   13  22.000000   47.230769
3   chr1    33332   16  15.125000   46.125000
4   chr1    33333   14  18.142857   42.642857
```

This answer is want I need. I just need to know if there's a way to do it better/faster.

Thanks!

Comment: Can I get some feedback on why this got downvoted? I'm doing my best here and it seems a bit harsh.

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension:

```
df['phred2'] = [(sum(map(ord,i))-len(i)*33)/len(i) for i in df["phred"]]
df["map2"] = [(sum(map(ord,i)))/len(i) for i in df["map"]]

  chrom    pos  depth              phred                map     phred2       map2
0  chr1  33329     17  33)'6'4?1&AB=?+..  X%&=E&!%,0("&"Y&!  18.000000  47.000000
1  chr1  33330     15    6+'/7=1@><C1*'*    X%=E!%,("&"Y&&!  18.533333  47.533333
2  chr1  33331     13      2*3A@/9@CC3--      X%E!%,("&"Y&!  22.000000  47.230769
3  chr1  33332     16   4**(,:3)+7-@<(0-   X%&E&!%,0("&"Y&!  15.125000  46.125000
4  chr1  33333     14     66(/C=*42A:.&*     X%=&!%0("&"&&!  18.142857  42.642857
```

Performance with 50k dummy data:

[image]